# Load multiple JSON files in spark sql from S3. Performance issue

Tags: json, scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have a amazon S3 folder containing multiple json files (100K +)
I would like to use spark sql to transform the data but I have performance issues.

If I do

```
val myjonDF = sqlContext.jsonFile("s3:/myfolder/")
```

It takes forever to complete. 
If you know a better way to this please share it with me!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried 100K+ file in S3 but have you tried this:

```
val myjonDF = sqlContext.jsonFile("s3a://myfolder/*")
```